# Python 3 Flask - 404 Page Not Found Error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I'm new to Flask and followed [this walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqr-e-dkkNI&t=346s) but am running into an issue. I want a user to be able to input text in a text field on the index.html page, hit the submit button, and take them to trader.html page. I'm running into a 404 Page Not Found error with my below code when the button is hit, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong? The URL bar shows the correct /trader.html address after the button is hit, but getting the 404 error page.

The 2 answers I found on SO for similar issues didn't work here as they mentioned that there needed to be a separate app.route to navigate them to the correct second page, but I already have that set up in my code???

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/trader', methods = ['POST'])
def trader_page():
    the_stock=request.form['inputted_stock']
    return render_template('trader.html')
```

index.html

```
<h1 style="color: #4485b8;">Welcome to the live stock trader!</h1>

<p>Select a stock ticker below to begin testing:</p>
<form action="/trader.html" method="POST">
<option value="AAPL">AAPL</option>
<option value="ABBV">ABBV</option>
<option value="ABT">ABT</option>
</select><br /><br /> 

<table>
<tr><td>Enter Stock Ticker</td><td><input type="text" name="inputted_stock" /></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
<p></p>
<table class="editorDemoTable" style="vertical-align: top;">
<thead></thead>
</table>
```

trader.html

```
<h1 style="color: #4485b8;">{{inputted_stock}} trader!</h1>
<p>Begin testing...</p>
```

Comment: Your flask route is `/trader' but you're POSTing to '/trader.html'. It's just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for your trader_page handler is just "/trader". So that's what you need to use in the form action.

```
<form action="/trader" method="POST">
```

Even better, use `url_for` to generate the URL:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('trader_page') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: beat me by seconds

Comment: Awesome! I was at a loss, but works now. Thanks a lot! Will mark this as answer when it becomes available.